# Android on Locale changed to "ar" menu app:actionLayout is not VISIBLE

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

When I am using "en" locale menu is VISIBLE, Please find the code i am using to create menu.

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_cart"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/cart_badge"
        android:title="@string/cart"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
```